# Removed Chat Blips Should Be... Removed

Tags: feature-request, chat

When a message is deleted, it says 'Removed'. Unfortunately, this gets very annoying when I'm trying to edit multiple chat messages together into a single message that is more useful if it is starred, as there are 2-5 'removed' messages right under it.

It would be nice to find a better solution to the 'removed' message. Maybe the transcript could have the 'removed' bar, but in regular chat it would disappear eventually? I'm not sure exactly how to fix this, but it seems like the current implementation discourages reducing messages into single, better quality messages.

Comment: +1, congrats on reaching 10k!

Comment: Oddly enough, it works the exact opposite at the moment; shows in live chat, but not in transcript.

Comment: Maybe we get rid of them after 2 minutes or something?

Answer (score 5):

I say multiple, adjacent messages that have been removed could be consolidated, with a number to boot.

Comment: I was talking to balpha about this earlier. It might be a nice compromise.

Answer (score 1):

They could delete all *nested* Removed lines.

Answer (score 0):

How about a set of posts belonging to one person which are all bunched together having a 'merge' command (or maybe all the posts should have 'merge up' and 'merge down' buttons, to give you a tiny bit more flexibility)